# regEx that match integer

Tags: javascript, regex, int

I need a regular expressions that matches all character that aren't allowed for an integer number, is it possible? So if there is '+' or '-' as first character the regEx doesn't match them but if is in the middle it matches. I need it for Javascript

ex. bold chars are matched (spaces also matches)
12367 **.** 23273 
+3782 
-322 **+** 7632 
123 **-** 21 
6789**asdf**6798

For everyone who downvote this post, please leave a reason in comments so I can improve it, thank you.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried with this ^-?\d+$, but i think that i have to negate it and I have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match either non-digit and not `+`/`-` or `+`/`-` preceded by something:

```
[^0-9+-]|(?<=.)[+-]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BJ7bay/1

For JavaScript (and other dialects not supporting lookbehinds) you may use another approach: replace all digits and `+`/`-` at the start with an empty string and you'll get all the desired chars as a result:

```js
console.log("-322 + 7632 ".replace(/^[+-]|\d+/g, ""));
```

Comment: Sorry, I need it for Javascript, my fault.